# Changing a value in an Object

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript.
I want to change the length of square using these methods. But it doesn't work. I cant find out, why. Plz help, without just down voting.

```js
// to change sideLength
this.set_sideLength = function(new_sideLength) {
    this.sideLength = new_sideLength;
};

var square = new Object();
square.sideLength = 6;
square.set_sideLength = set_sideLength;

// Calculate perimeter
square.calcPerimeter = function() {
  return this.sideLength * 4;
};


var p = square.calcPerimeter();

// output
console.log("Perimeter is: " + p + ", if side length is "+ sideLength);

// New ouptput with new sideLength
square.set_sideLength(10);
console.log("Perimeter is: " + p + ", if side length is "+ sideLength);
```

Comment: If you look at the console you will know why it doesn't work: `ReferenceError: sideLength is not defined`.

Comment: Yes it is. sideLength = 6 then i am trying to change to 10.

Comment: `square.sideLength = 6;` sets the **property** `slideLength` of the **object** `square`. It does **not** create a **variable** `sideLength`. Do you really think that it is more likely that the browser makes a mistake instead of you? If the console shows an error that something is not defined, then it is not defined.

Comment: You have not called `calcPerimeter` function second time also `sideLength` should be called as `square.sideLength`. See my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions seem quite fine.  It is the console.logs you perform are on the old values and not accessing the property on the object.After setting the `sideLength` to 10 you don't request the new `calcPerimeter` for that `sideLength`. And you need to access the `sideLength` on the `square` object like `square.sideLength`

```js
// to change sideLength
this.set_sideLength = function(new_sideLength) {
    this.sideLength = new_sideLength;
};

var square = new Object();
square.sideLength = 6;
square.set_sideLength = set_sideLength;

// Calculate perimeter
square.calcPerimeter = function() {
  return this.sideLength * 4;
};


var p = square.calcPerimeter();

// output
console.log("Perimeter is: " + p + ", if side length is "+ square.sideLength);

// New ouptput with new sideLength
square.set_sideLength(10);
p = square.calcPerimeter();
console.log("Perimeter is: " + p + ", if side length is "+ square.sideLength);
```

Like @Felix Kling mentions you should probably change

```js
// from
this.set_sideLength = function(new_sideLength) {
    this.sideLength = new_sideLength;
};

// to
function set_sideLength(new_sideLength) {
    this.sideLength = new_sideLength;
};
```

Assigning the function to a property on `this` could have different effects based on what `this` actually is. In your context is probably represents the `window` object. Which is why the following works.

```

```
square.set_sideLength = set_sideLength;
```

```

In general it is considered bad practice to add properties to the window object. You would therefore be better of using the other approach and wrapping the whole thing is an IIFE.

Like so

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
// to change sideLength
function set_sideLength(new_sideLength) {
    this.sideLength = new_sideLength;
}

var square = new Object();
square.sideLength = 6;
square.set_sideLength = set_sideLength;

// Calculate perimeter
square.calcPerimeter = function calcPerimeter() {
  return this.sideLength * 4;
};


var p = square.calcPerimeter();

// output
console.log("Perimeter is: " + p + ", if side length is "+ square.sideLength);

// New ouptput with new sideLength
square.set_sideLength(10);
p = square.calcPerimeter();
console.log("Perimeter is: " + p + ", if side length is "+ square.sideLength);
})();
```

Comment: How can the code be fine if it throws errors? `this.set_sideLength = function(new_sideLength) {}` should really be `function set_sideLength(new_sideLength) {}` btw

Comment: The functions them selfs. Perhaps i should have clarified that better :)

Comment: @FelixKling because the way he called the functions was correct, and there was only one thing that needed to be fixed. Cut OP some slack.

Answer (score 0):

You have not called `calcPerimeter` function second time also `sideLength` should be called as `square.sideLength`.

```js
// to change sideLength
this.set_sideLength = function(new_sideLength) {
    this.sideLength = new_sideLength;
};

var square = new Object();
square.sideLength = 6;
square.set_sideLength = set_sideLength;

// Calculate perimeter
square.calcPerimeter = function() {
  return this.sideLength * 4;
};


var p = square.calcPerimeter();

// output
document.write("Perimeter is: " + p + ", if side length is "+ square.sideLength);

// New ouptput with new sideLength
square.set_sideLength(10);
 var p = square.calcPerimeter();
document.write("<br/>Perimeter is: " + p + ", if side length is "+ square.sideLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Square(){}

Square.prototype.setSideLength = function( sideLength ) {
    this.sideLength = sideLength;
};

var square = new Square();
square.sideLength = 6;

Square.prototype.calcPerimeter = function() {
  return this.sideLength * 4;
};

console.log("Perimeter is: " + square.calcPerimeter() +
   ", if side length is "+ square.sideLength);

square.setSideLength(10);
console.log("Perimeter is: " + square.calcPerimeter() +
   ", if side length is "+ square.sideLength);
```

Console:

[image: Firefox console]